# Specifying input for data dynamically

Tags: c++

So I have a great many text files and I'm trying to put them into a database. However the files are written by a multitude of people. and come in ALLLLL different formats.

Instead of writing a program for each file to import it, id like to try to make one program that can import them all. But I cant quite wrap my head around how to process it.

This is what I would like to do:

```
#>prog somfile.txt
File data format?: U\tT:D
```

I got the db and ext ready I'm just not sure how to build a delimited list parser.

In my program, id like to get; per line something like:

```
std::string format = U\tT:D ; //set from input
std::string line = "Bob Dole<tab>11-13-17:25"; //Set from txt file readline
map<std::string,char> out = somefunc(line,format);
```

And I expect:

```
out['U'] = "bob";
out['T'] = "11-13-17";
out['D'] = "25";
out['n'] = ""; //Nothing cause it wasn't there.
```

I cant think of a way to do this, cause the data can have almost any character in it. And there are some types that come after others. I just need pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Why don't you use regular expressions instead of coming up with your own data format language?

Comment: @Barmar The files I am getting are from other people. And there is no standard on how its input. Only thing that is standard is one entry per line on file.

Comment: I mean use a regular expression instead of `U\tT:D`

Comment: Anyway, the answer is that there's no simple solution for this, you have to write a parser.

Comment: Can a regex be used like that? Ifso, Im all for it.

Comment: You can use named capture groups to do it.

Comment: I'd check out regexr.com if you aren't very familiar with regex.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do what you described, however, if you can standardize certain components you can make it easier for yourself.  Also if these are being fed into a database, you need to have some structure built out to map everything correctly.

**An example project I have worked on :**

1. Reports come in from different source systems, of varying file types
2. These reports need to be fed directly into the database

In this case, I used both a Flat-File to XML converter and an XML to XLSX converter.  The source system would provide an "XML" looking file and I already had an XLSX converter in place from a previous project.  There are plenty of resources online that can help you achieve this, but I'd advise you avoid some headaches by restricting the inputs.

**Further elaboration:**

I converted various file types into an XML file.  Once I had the XML file I would map various fields to another XML file which would be my template (JDOM/JNI), the component that standardizes what actually will go in the database.  You can then use regex based on important fields that may need to be formatted in a specific way such as a date format or monetary values. This way we standardize the various fields.  Then I posted the finalized component through a web service, SOAP UI.

**Possible issues:**

1. Special characters - You can handle this with either a script or directly within your program
2. File Type Limitations - The more file types you accept, the more conversions you'll have to make especially if there are various delimiters separating the data.